# Which file system automatically stores hashes of files?

Tags: filesystems, hashing, checksum, data-integrity

Which file system automatically computes and stores hashes of files and later checks them at access to detect corruption?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sun's [ZFS does](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gaypb/index.html):

> With ZFS, all data and metadata is
>   checksummed using a user-selectable
>   algorithm. Traditional file systems
>   that do provide checksumming have
>   performed it on a per-block basis, out
>   of necessity due to the volume
>   management layer and traditional file
>   system design. The traditional design
>   means that certain failure modes, such
>   as writing a complete block to an
>   incorrect location, can result in
>   properly checksummed data that is
>   actually incorrect. ZFS checksums are
>   stored in a way such that these
>   failure modes are detected and can be
>   recovered from gracefully. All
>   checksumming and data recovery is done
>   at the file system layer, and is
>   transparent to applications.

And so [does Linux's btrfs](http://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ): Btrfs also supports both data and metadata checksumming. Data checksumming is optional and can be disabled by mounting with `-o nodatasum`.

Comment: Further, if your filesystem is mirrored, I believe it can recover from the error.

Comment: No, neither of them stores hashes of _files_. All they do is _block-level_ checksums. However, that covers the data integrity issue OP is asking about.